# MySQL BETWEEN query not using index

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, mariadb

I have geoip data in a table, `network_start_ip` and `network_end_ip` are `varbinary(16)` columns with the result of `INET6_ATON(ip_start/end)` as values. 2 other columns are latitude and longitude.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `ipblocks` (
 `network_start_ip` varbinary(16) NOT NULL,
 `network_last_ip` varbinary(16) NOT NULL,
 `latitude` double NOT NULL,
 `longitude` double NOT NULL,
 KEY `network_start_ip` (`network_start_ip`),
 KEY `network_last_ip` (`network_last_ip`),
 KEY `idx_range` (`network_start_ip`,`network_last_ip`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

As you can see I have created 3 indexes for testing. Why does my (quite simple) query

```sql
SELECT 
    latitude, longitude
FROM
    ipblocks b
WHERE
    INET6_ATON('82.207.219.33') BETWEEN b.network_start_ip AND b.network_last_ip
```

not use any these indexes?

[image: result of EXPLAIN]

The query takes ~3 seconds which is way too long to use it in production.

Comment: InnoDB tables really need a `PRIMARY KEY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) I found the optimal query for my question.

```sql
SELECT b.* FROM 
  (SELECT b.* FROM ipblocks b WHERE b.network_start_ip <= INET6_ATON('82.207.219.33') 
                              ORDER BY b.network_start_ip DESC LIMIT 1 ) 
b WHERE INET6_ATON('82.207.219.33') <= network_last_ip
```

Now we select the blocks ***smaller*** than `INET6_ATON(82.207.219.33)` in the inner query but we order them ***descending*** which enables us to use the `LIMIT 1` again.

Query response time is now .002 to .004 seconds. Great!

Comment: Assuming that there are records and they are not overlapping, I think that the outer block testing for the last_ip is not necessary.  `SELECT b.* FROM ipblocks b WHERE b.network_start_ip <= INET6_ATON('82.207.219.33') 
                              ORDER BY b.network_start_ip DESC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because there are two columns referenced -- and that is really hard to optimize.  Assuming that there are no overlapping IP ranges, you can restructure the query as:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM (SELECT b.*
      FROM ipblocks b
      WHERE b.network_start_ip <= INET6_ATON('82.207.219.33')
      ORDER BY b.network_start_ip DESC
      LIMIT 1
     ) b
WHERE INET6_ATON('82.207.219.33') <= network_last_ip;
```

The inner query should use an index on `ipblocks(network_start_ip)`.  The outer query is only comparing one row, so it does not need any index.

Or as:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM (SELECT b.*
      FROM ipblocks b
      WHERE b.network_last_ip >= INET6_ATON('82.207.219.33')
      ORDER BY b.network_end_ip ASC
      LIMIT 1
     ) b
WHERE network_last_ip <= INET6_ATON('82.207.219.33');
```

This would use an index on `(network_last_ip)`.  MySQL (and I think MariaDB) does a better job with ascending sorts than descending sorts.

Comment: This is not the solution, but it helps speed up. The `LIMIT 1` is not possible because `network_start_ip` must be **smaller** than `INET6_ATON('82.207.219.33')` and there are many which are smaller. Without using LIMIT 1 and together with the outer query the result is correct and the query speeds up to .8 seconds. Still not really good but it's a start :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does this query give you correct results? Your start/end IPs seem to be stored as a binary string while you're searching for an integer representation.
I would first make sure that network_start_ip and network_last_ip are unsigned INT fields with the integer representation of the IP addresses. This is assuming that you work with IPv4 only:

```
CREATE TABLE ipblocks_int AS
SELECT
    INET_ATON(network_start_ip) as network_start_ip,
    INET_ATON(network_last_ip) as network_last_ip,
    latitude,
    longitude
FROM ipblocks
```

Then use (network_start_ip,network_last_ip) as primary key.

Comment: `INET6_ATON()` returns a binary string.  You have misinterpreted the question.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I have overlooked the "6" in INET6_ATON indeed. Still suggest to try using the pair as primary key.

Comment: @Alex - Edit your Answer to include `6` and a `PRIMARY KEY`.  (If you need more reputation points, take the tutorial; it's and easy 100 points.)

Answer (score 0):

It's a tough problem.  There is no simple solution.

The reason it is tough is that it is effectively

```
   start <= 123  AND
   last  >= 123
```

Regardless of what indexes are available, the Optimizer will work with one or the other of those.  With `INDEX(start, ...)`, it will pick `start <= 123` it will scan the first part of the index.  Similarly for the other clause.  One of those scans more than half the index, the other scans less -- but not enough less to be worth using an index.  Moving it into the `PRIMARY KEY` will help with some cases, but it is hardly worth the effort.

Bottom line, not matter what you do in the way of `INDEX` or `PRIMARY KEY`, *most* IP constants will lead to more than 1.5 seconds for the query.

Do your start/last IP ranges overlap?  If so, that adds complexity.  In particular, overlaps would probably invalidate Gordon's `LIMIT 1`.

My solution involves requires non-overlapping regions.  Any gaps in IPs necessitate 'unowned' ranges of IPs.  This is because there is only a start_ip; the last_ip is implied by being less than the start of the next item in the table.  See  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges  (It includes code for IPv4 and for IPv6.)

Meanwhile, `DOUBLE` for lat/lng is overkill:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices